# How do I access the image in AsyncImage to save the image after it's been retrieved? ( SwiftUI )

Tags: ios, swiftui, asyncimageview

I'm currently trying to find a way to save an image from `AsyncImage` so I can cache it right away (without using a separate image retrieval process).

This is my code for `AsyncImage` and the Extension on `View` I'm using to try to save it.

```swift
AsyncImage(url: asyncUrl) { phase in
    
    switch phase {
    case .empty:
        ProgressView()
    case .success(let image):
        image
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
        urlImageModel.image = image.snapshot()
    case .failure:
        Image(uiImage: UrlImageView.defaultImage!)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
    @unknown default:
        Image(uiImage: UrlImageView.defaultImage!)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
    }
}

extension View {
    func snapshot() -> UIImage {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        let view = controller.view
        
        let targetSize = controller.view.intrinsicContentSize
        view?.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize)
        view?.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: targetSize)
        
        return renderer.image { _ in
            view?.drawHierarchy(in: controller.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I put the code in `case .success` to save the image in my `urlImageModel`, it gives this error:

Type `()` cannot conform to `View` in reference to the `image` closure.

Any ideas on how to save the image from within `AsyncImage` would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

The `content` closure you're passing to `AsyncImage` is a `@ViewBuilder`. That means that every statement that isn't a declaration (like `let x = ...`) or control flow (like `if blah { ... }`) needs to be an expression that evaluates to some `View`. The problem is with this statement:

```
urlImageModel.image = image.snapshot()
```

That isn't a declaration or control flow. It's an assignment. Swift treats it like it evaluates to a `Void` value (also written `()`, the empty tuple), and `Void` is not a `View`.

You can fix it by wrapping it in a declaration. But another thing to watch out for is that you should never change your model objects during SwiftUI's redisplay phase (during which it asks a `View` for its `body`). So you should also dispatch it to be safe. The dispatched block will be run later, outside of SwiftUI's redisplay phase.

```swift
let _ = DispatchQueue.main.async {
    urlImageModel.image = image.snapshot()
}
```

Comment: Thank you, adding the DispatchQueue worked great!

Answer (score 2):

you could simply use this, works well for me:

```
 image
     .resizable()
     .scaledToFit()
     .onAppear {
         urlImageModel.image = image.snapshot()
     }
```

Comment: This doesn't work because `onAppear` is called only once.