# How to pre-load Async Image in Swift/Swftui

Tags: ios, swift, caching, swiftui

I have an application that loads some user profile photos, in a couple of different views but whenever I navigate to the view it displays a 1-second loading animation before displaying it. Can I preload the async image, or is there another workaround to avoid displaying the loading animation.

I currently just have the standard async image with the progressview placeholder.

Comment: There are many ways to address your requirements. You could just use
                `let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)` 
                to download your photos once (in parallel) and store them locally. You could also try this 
                approach: [caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69214543/how-can-i-add-caching-to-asyncimage) or this: [retrieve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68854131/how-do-i-access-the-image-in-asyncimage-to-save-the-image-after-its-been-retrie)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! A general advice, stick to fixed names, like SwiftUI, AsyncImage, ProgressView etc. It’s  just easier to read & understand.